# how to loop through and manipulate array (Morris.bar)

Tags: php, arrays, morris.js

I'm having trouble getting my data (from mysql) in a bar chart (Morris.bar). I have my desired results in an array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [total] => 200.00
        [year] => 2015
        [month] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [total] => 500.00
        [year] => 2015
        [month] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [total] => 500.00
        [year] => 2016
        [month] => 2
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [total] => 600.00
        [year] => 2016
        [month] => 3
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [total] => 600.00
        [year] => 2016
        [month] => 4
    )

)
```

I want to get the data in the bar charts like this (always present all months and if no value or empty value then echo 0 (zero))

```
{month: "<?php echo $months[0]; ?>", <?php echo $last_year; ?>:VALUE_THAT_BELONGS_TO_JAN_2015(LAST_YEAR), <?php echo $this_year; ?>: VALUE_THAT_BELONGS_TO_JAN_2016 (CURRENT YEAR)},
```

Complete script now:

```
<?php $months = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"); ?>
 Morris.Bar({
element: 'graph_invoices_month',
data : [
{month: "<?php echo $months[0]; ?>", <?php echo $last_year; ?>: 1000, <?php echo $this_year; ?>: 1100},
{month: "<?php echo $months[1]; ?>", <?php echo $last_year; ?>: 3351, <?php echo $this_year; ?>: 629},
{month: "<?php echo $months[2]; ?>", <?php echo $last_year; ?>: 3269, <?php echo $this_year; ?>: 618},
{month: "<?php echo $months[3]; ?>", <?php echo $last_year; ?>: 3246, <?php echo $this_year; ?>: 661},
{month: "<?php echo $months[4]; ?>", <?php echo $last_year; ?>: 3257, <?php echo $this_year; ?>: 667},
{month: "<?php echo $months[5]; ?>", <?php echo $last_year; ?>: 3248, <?php echo $this_year; ?>: 627},
{month: "<?php echo $months[6]; ?>", <?php echo $last_year; ?>: 3171, <?php echo $this_year; ?>: 660},
{month: "<?php echo $months[7]; ?>", <?php echo $last_year; ?>: 3171, <?php echo $this_year; ?>: 676},
{month: "<?php echo $months[8]; ?>", <?php echo $last_year; ?>: 3201, <?php echo $this_year; ?>: 656},
{month: "<?php echo $months[9]; ?>", <?php echo $last_year; ?>: 3215, <?php echo $this_year; ?>: 622},
{month: "<?php echo $months[10]; ?>", <?php echo $last_year; ?>: 3215, <?php echo $this_year; ?>: 622},
{month: "<?php echo $months[11]; ?>", <?php echo $last_year; ?>: 3215, <?php echo $this_year; ?>: 622}

],

xkey: 'month',
ykeys: ['<?php echo $last_year; ?>', '<?php echo $this_year; ?>'],
labels: ['<?php echo $last_year; ?>', '<?php echo $this_year; ?>'],
resize: true,
barColors: ['<?php echo $this_year_color; ?>', '<?php echo $last_year_color; ?>'],
xLabelAngle: 60
});
```

Further clarification: This is what I'm after:

```
month: Jan 2015 = 0 : Jan 2016 = 0
month: Feb 2015 = 200 : Feb 2016 = 500
month: Mar 2015 = 500 : Mar 2016 = 600
month: Apr 2015 = 0 : Apr 2016 = 600
month: May 2015 = 0 : May 2016 = 0
month: Jun 2015 = 0 : Jun 2016 = 0
month: Jul 2015 = 0 : Jul 2016 = 0
month: Aug 2015 = 0 : Aug 2016 = 0
month: Sep 2015 = 0 : Sep 2016 = 0
month: Oct 2015 = 0 : Oct 2016 = 0
month: Nov 2015 = 0 : Nov 2016 = 0
month: Dec 2015 = 0 : Dec 2016 = 0
```

Hope someone can shed a light on this 'cause it's drivng me nuts! Thanks in advance for the help!

### D.

Comment: I'm unclear what exactly the question or problem is...!?

Comment: Hi thanks for asking: 

have a look at "Further clarification: This is what I'm after:": what php code would be needed to accomplish that. This is of course the desired output but the script above should hold those values. How do I loop through the array to get this: month->year_last ->value[total]   - - month->year_current->value[total].

hope this clarifies

Comment: It seems that the question is just how to loop through and manipulate array, so you just need to show the first and last block of code.

Comment: Thanks zcui93, that would probably the question and sorry for the confusion: Hard to describe.... All the needed code is already given above. The only thing that wasn't given is the name of the variable that holds the array: $total_revenue_by_months. Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

Phewww, I managed to answer my own question. If others need a similar solution this is my code that did the trick:

```
    <?php $months = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"); ?>
    Morris.Bar({
    element: 'graph_invoices_month',
    data : [
      <?php foreach($months as $month => $value){ ?>
        {month: "<?php echo $value; ?>", 
      <?php echo $last_year; ?>: 

      <?php $total_revenue_last_year = 0; ?>
      <?php foreach($total_revenue_by_months as $total_revenue_by_month){ ?>
      <?php if (($month + 1) == $total_revenue_by_month['month'] && $last_year == $total_revenue_by_month['year']) { ?>
      <?php $total_revenue_last_year =  $total_revenue_by_month['total_month_revenue']; ?> 
      <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if (isset($total_revenue_last_year)){
        echo $total_revenue_last_year . ",";
        } else { echo "0,"; } ?>


      <?php echo $this_year; ?>: 
      <?php $total_revenue_this_year = 0; ?>
      <?php foreach($total_revenue_by_months as $total_revenue_by_month){ ?>
      <?php if (($month + 1) == $total_revenue_by_month['month'] && $this_year == $total_revenue_by_month['year']) { ?>
      <?php $total_revenue_this_year =  $total_revenue_by_month['total_month_revenue']; ?> 
      <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if (isset($total_revenue_this_year)){
        echo $total_revenue_this_year . "},";
        } else { echo "0},"; } ?>

      <?php }  ?>          
    ],

    xkey: 'month',
    ykeys: ['<?php echo $last_year; ?>', '<?php echo $this_year; ?>'],
    labels: ['<?php echo $last_year; ?>', '<?php echo $this_year; ?>'],
    resize: true,
    barColors: ['<?php echo $this_year_color; ?>', '<?php echo $last_year_color; ?>'],
    xLabelAngle: 60
});
```